Kivy android app - pyjnius.PythonJavaClass not working with buildozer when using a custom interface in __javainterfaces__
This is a simplified version of a bigger app that requires a java class to have a python implementation so that a callback object that has to be java can call python methods, you can find the project here: https://github.com/lookbehindyounow/remote_mouse
I made this version to try & isolate the issue, basically all it does is launch a kivy app & prints "hi" to the console.
main.py:
from jnius import autoclass, PythonJavaClass, java_method
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Print(PythonJavaClass):
    __javainterfaces__=["com/example/IPrint"]
    @java_method("(Ljava/lang/String;)V")
    def jprint(self,message):
        print(message)

Holder=autoclass("com.example.Holder")
JavaPrint=autoclass("com.example.Print")

class Test(App):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.printer=Print()
        # self.printer=JavaPrint()
        self.holder=Holder(self.printer)
        self.holder.jprint("hi")
    
    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()

class MainWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Label(text="kivy working"))

Test().run()

Print.java:
package com.example;

import com.example.IPrint;

public class Print implements IPrint{
    public void jprint(String message){
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}

IPrint.java:
package com.example;

public interface IPrint{
    public void jprint(String message);
}

Holder.java:
package com.example;
import com.example.IPrint;

public class Holder{
    public IPrint printer;
    public Holder(IPrint printer){
        this.printer=printer;
    }
    public void jprint(String message){
        this.printer.jprint(message);
    }
}

Here's some parts of buildozer.spec separated by elipses, the rest is all default settings:
# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,java
...
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,pyjnius
...
# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
android.add_src = java

error:
<originating from main.py: self.printer=Print()>
jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: interface com.example.IPrint is not visible from class loader java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

If in main.py I uncomment self.printer=JavaPrint() it works fine, so I know what's wrong is to do with Print(PythonJavaClass), but idk what. If I misspell __javainterfaces__=["com/example/IPrint"] it gives a different error:
<originating from main.py: self.printer=Print()>
jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Didn't find class "com.example.IPrintaaa" on path: <long path> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

So I know __javainterfaces__=["com/example/IPrint"] is picking up the right thing. What's more is it runs fine on my macbook, it's the app built with buildozer that isn't working on my android phone.
I've tried compiling the java classes into a jar file & updating the spec file accordingly, no difference. A second jar file just for IPrint throws an error saying duplicate resources. I haven't been able to load an interface successfully using pyjnius autoclass or JavaClass, it gives a different error when instantiating Print(PythonJavaClass) but one that also happens on the macbook.
Hope this all makes sense, cheers.

Fixed it, was annoyingly simple, just needed different context for PythonJavaClass
class Print(PythonJavaClass):
    __javainterfaces__=["com/example/IPrint"]
    __javacontext__="app"
    @java_method("(Ljava/lang/String;)V")
    def jprint(self,message):
        print(message)

